# How to bind input type hidden with Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In my form I have an input element with `type = "hidden"`. I m updating the value of the element from jQuery triggered by a
Drop-Down which is outside the form. I've bind the element with Livewire property using `wire:model="examId"` but it's not working. when I change the `type` to `text` it works.

so how can I bind `input type = "hidden"` to Livewire or is there any other way to pass the value of the element to Livewire when changed.

```html
<input wire:model="examId" type="hidden" name="examId" id="examId">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Livewire does not listen for updates to hidden inputs, but you can instead emit events to change a property in Livewire. This means you can set the property from any script on that page.

In your JavaScript, emit the event and pass in the data,

```js
let examId = 32;
Livewire.emit('setExamId', examId);
```

In your component, listen for that event and declare the method which performs the logic of setting that ID,

```php
protected $listeners = ['setExamId'];

public function setExamId($examId)
{
    $this->examId = $examId;
}
```